# Whitelisting, preventing XSS with WMD control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, wmd, whitelist

Are there any problems with what I am doing here?  This is my first time to deal with something like this, and I just want to make sure I understand all the risks, etc. to different methods.

I am using WMD to get user input, and I am displaying it with a literal control.
Since it is uneditable once entered I will be storing the HTML and not the Markdown,

```
input = Server.HTMLEncode(stringThatComesFromWMDTextArea)
```

And then run something like the following for tags I want users to be able to use.

```
// Unescape whitelisted tags.
string output = input.Replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>").Replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>")
                     .Replace("&lt;i&gt;", "<i>").Replace("&lt;/i&gt;", "</i>");
```

**Edit** Here is what I am doing currently:

```
 public static string EncodeAndWhitelist(string html)
 {
     string[] whiteList = { "b", "i", "strong", "img", "ul", "li" };
     string encodedHTML = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
     foreach (string wl in whiteList)
         encodedHTML = encodedHTML.Replace("&lt;" + wl + "&gt;", "<" + wl + ">").Replace("&lt;/" + wl + "&gt;", "</" + wl + ">");
     return encodedHTML;
 }
```

1. Will what I am doing here keep me protected from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?
2. Are there any other considerations
   that should be made?
3. Is there a good list of normal
   tags to whitelist?

Comment: That code won't work for the "IMG" tag since replacing "&lt;img&gt;" doesn't allow for the "src" attribute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirements really are that basic that you can do such simple string replacements then yes, this is ‘safe’ against XSS. (However, it's still possible to submit non-well-formed content where `<i>` and `<b>` are mis-nested or unclosed, which could potentially mess up the page the content ends up inserted into.)

But this is rarely enough. For example currently `<a href="...">` or `<img src="..." />` are not allowed. If you wanted to allow these or other markup with attribute values in, you'd have a whole lot more work to do. You might then approach it with regex, but that gives you endless problems with accidental nesting and replacement of already-replaced content, seeing as how regex can't parse HTML, and that.

To solve both problems, the usual approach is to use an [X][HT]ML parser on the input, then walk the DOM removing all but known-good elements and attributes, then finally re-serialise to [X]HTML. The result is then guaranteed well-formed and contains only safe content.

Comment: So, assuming I wanted something more robust, what would you suggest for the parsers you mentioned?  Could HTML Agility Pack handle it?

Is there not something that does all this already?

Comment: Yes, HTML Agility Pack is a good choice. Once you've got the DOM parsed it's a relatively trivial exercise to write a recursive function that removes all but known-good elements/attributes from the DOM tree. Also if you allow `href`/`src`/etc., remember to check the URLs for known-good schemes like `http`/`https`, to avoid injection through `javascript:` URLs and the like.